RewriteRule not working in htaccess. gives the same url as in the href tag
my .htaccess file's full code is
# BEGIN 

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/show_article/([0-9]+)\.php /show_article.php?article_id=$1


# END 

i want url as 'mysite.com/show_article/17' for the link 'mysite.com/show_article?article_id=17'
.htaccess file is working, but the RewriteRule is not working. i am getting the same url (mysite.com/show_article?article_id=17).   is anything missing in the .htaccess file? can anybody help me out?

Try this out:
# BEGIN

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^show_article/(\d+)$ mysite/show_article?article_id=$1 [QSA,L]

# END

This will only work if your server has mod_rewrite enabled.
Make sure to clear your browser cache or use an incognito window to test the redirection.

@R K   Tried your code. received the following error.  the received url is http://localhost/show_article/17
Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.

@EighTainment I adjusted the code and removed the redirect. Try again.

@R K,  Yea i tried this new code bro, now the page is working, but not url Re written, same url (mysite.com/show_article?article_id=17) only comes

Do you have mod_rewrite enabled?

@R K, yes bro,  in xampp\apache\conf  httpd.conf
#LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so #LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so #LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so #LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so

Great! Did you try the updated code?

@R K, yes bro tried with updated code.  same URL only coming (localhost/mysite/show_article?article_id=17). I cleared all cookies and browse history too. but no use.....

Hmm... Have you by chance tried to access "mysite.com/show_article/17" to see if it resolves? I'll play around with it more too.

direct entry of 'http://localhost/mysite/show_article/17'  says "Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.58 (Win64) OpenSSL/3.1.3 PHP/8.2.12 Server at localhost Port 80"

hi @R K, when directly check the url (mysite.com/show_article/17) it is working.... but while click through page url (show_article.php?id=17) it is not working(ie.. page works, but url shows the same as show_article.php?id=17...)  and the actual code in .htaccess file is below..

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^show_article/(\d+)$ show_article.php?article_id=$1 [L]

# END```

@EighTainment "(ie.. page works, but url shows the same as show_article.php?id=17...)" - the rule you have only rewrites incoming requests; it does not change what your links in your HTML point to in the first place. You could add a rule, that redirects requests in the "old" format to the new one, but that should only be necessary, if you have old, "outside" links you can not control. Outputting the correct new link format in the HTML you yourself create, is not mod_rewrite's job.
